# Is it safe to pass a field by reference into unmanaged code?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

Is it safe to pass a field by reference into an unmanaged extern method?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SomeStruct
{
    public int SomeValue;
}

class SomeClass
{
    SomeStruct _someStruct;

    [DllImport("SomeLibrary.dll")]
    static extern void SomeExternMethod(ref SomeStruct someStruct);

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Is this safe or do I have to pin the current instance of SomeClass?
        SomeExternMethod(ref _someStruct);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a look at the IL code and it seems to use a direct reference to the field, which would support the idea that I have to pin it. I'd like to know for sure though.

Comment: It's no different from passing any other variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

P/Invoke will pin direct arguments which are passed by `ref` or `out`, *for the duration of the call*.  They will show up on the unmanaged side as a pointer.

As long as the unmanaged code doesn't save the pointer for later, you're ok.  If it will save the pointer for later, then you need to use `GCHandle.Alloc(Pinned)` to pin it until whenever "later" means.